# g++.exe: fatal error: no input files Notepad++ error

Tags: c++

I am trying to set up Notepad++ with a c++ compiler.  So far I have run into the following issue:

```
g++.exe: error: ôone.cppö: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I was previously running into the problem:

```
CreateProcess() failed with error code 2: The system cannot find the file specified
```

So, I corrected the file locations and this began showing up

```
 g++.exe: error: ôone.cppö: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

This the full print by the way.

```
NPP_SAVE: C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\C++\one.cpp
CD: C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\C++
Current directory: C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\C++
C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\pocketcpp\pocketcpp\MinGW\bin\g++.exe “one.cpp”
Process started >>>
g++.exe: error: ôone.cppö: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
cmd /c “C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\C++\a.exe”
Process started >>>
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe g++ does not require putting quotes around the input file. See if you can adjust the macros in notepad++ to reflect that.

Comment: You're using the weird unicode "smart quotes". Replace them with normal quotes.

Comment: No program ever required quotes around arguments passed on the commandline. You need quotes in order to instruct the shell how to handle different parts of the commandline, but they shouldn't be passed to the started program after that.

Comment: Well I guess that was a beginner's mistake on my part.  Thank you all very much for that advice.  The only thing that remains is:                                               The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: quotes are required for filenames containing spaces.